# how can I group nodes with all the properties of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I got a requirement that I have to get the nodes that grouped by all the properties of the nodes. it likes this: I have 2 nodes in neo4j db that has properties 'Name' and 'Address' that I can write the cypher sql like this: start node=node(0) match node-->record return count(*),record.Name,record.address. It can be easy. but now the problem is that I have lots of properties maybe 50s and the property names are not fixed, I writes the cypher like this: start node=node(0) match node-->record return count(*), record, but it can not get the result that I want. Can anybody give a hand?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
...
return record.Name!, record.Address!
```

Or:

```
where has(record.Name) and has(record.Address)
...
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my meaning, sorry about this. My mean is that if I have 50 properties of the node, I want to check the duplicated nodes that all the property values is the same, then how can I do this? if I write all the properties like your suggestion, it looks very bad, to be honest.

Comment: Hmm. Can you describe your graph and what you want the output of the query to be? Maybe an example in console.neo4j.org would help...

Comment: Sorry, I almost forget I've raise this question. I vote, so maybe it can help the other guy, though it's not very helpful for me. I convinced the client to change the requirement, thank you sir. BTW, it's hard to find resource for Neo4j.